# What is the purpose of having one endpoint for the whole app?

Tags: rest, api, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I'm building a web app with Laravel for scheduling emails and when I was checking out the competitors, I noticed that one of them is using only one endpoint for all the requests and sending different payload in the POST request.

I thought of building my app's API the same way but I really don't find the use of this point.

Comment: Check this out maybe you find it usefull, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651569/single-api-endpoint-pros-and-cons

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that one of them is using only one endpoint for all the requests and sending different payload in the POST request.

It's a common approach to use when you want transport agnostic messaging.  See, for example, [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP).